# Remove non-ASCII characters

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I have a problem where odd characters (from Word etc) are getting into a field in the database and then when I am showing that field it is showing spurious characters.

Is it possible with a RegEx to remove any non-ASCII characters? Obviously I want people to still be able to use any special characters like !@£$%^&*()_-+= etc just not non-ASCII characters.

If anyone could help that would be great!

Many Thanks!

Updated: This is in CLASSIC ASP.

Comment: define "non-UK characters". Do you mean non ASCII letters?

Comment: If this should be really a regex problem, you need to tell us the language you are using. asp-classic is not a language.

Comment: Sorry I've added Classic ASP. I guess non-ASCII letters should be removed from the string, that would make sense

Comment: this question is already tagged "asp-classic", no need to add it in the text. I am not a web programmer, but as I know, ASP is not a programming language itself, you can use together with ASP different scripting languages, and the regular expression you are able to use, depends on which language you are using.

Comment: `Response.Charset = "utf-8"`?

Comment: I queued an edit to the question to specify non-ASCII characters.  But you probably want to be more specific than that.  What about accented ASCII characters in the range À-ÿ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this task you will need to build up various regular expressions and execute them with a sub routine call before inserting your record into the database.

Here is an excerpt from an explanation from [1stclassmedia](http://www.1stclassmedia.co.uk/developers/clean-ms-word-formatting.php).

```
str = str.replace( /\s*FONT-FAMILY:[^;"]*;?/gi, "" ) ;
str = str.replace(/<(\w[^>]*) class=([^ |>]*)([^>]*)/gi, "<$1$3") ;
str = str.replace( /<(\w[^>]*) style="([^\"]*)"([^>]*)/gi, "<$1$3" ) ;
str = str.replace( /\s*style="\s*"/gi, '' ) ; 
str = str.replace( /<SPAN\s*[^>]*>\s*&nbsp;\s*<\/SPAN>/gi, '&nbsp;' ) ; 
str = str.replace( /<SPAN\s*[^>]*><\/SPAN>/gi, '' ) ; 
str = str.replace(/<(\w[^>]*) lang=([^ |>]*)([^>]*)/gi, "<$1$3") ; 
str = str.replace( /<SPAN\s*>(.*?)<\/SPAN>/gi, '$1' ) ; 
str = str.replace( /<FONT\s*>(.*?)<\/FONT>/gi, '$1' ) ;
//some RegEx code for the picky browsers
var re = new RegExp("(<P)([^>]*>.*?)(<\/P>)","gi") ;
str = str.replace( re, "<div$2</div>" ) ;
var re2 = new RegExp("(<font|<FONT)([^*>]*>.*?)(<\/FONT>|<\/font>)","gi") ; 
str = str.replace( re2, "<div$2</div>") ;
str = str.replace( /size|SIZE = ([\d]{1})/g, '' ) ;
```